# SQl Use IIF to compare 2 values in same row

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I am using SQL in MS Access and need to compare 2 values in a row to determine the result of a 3rd field. 
The "Yearmove" field does not have a value in all cases. Here is the test code I am running

```
SELECT z.SCHOOL, z.Year as Year,  ProgBuild.BldgNo, ProgMoveBuild.yearmove AS Yearmove,
IIF([Year]=[Yearmove], 1, 0) AS Result
```

The results are fine in the cases where "Yearmove" is blank, and show 0 as expected. Anyplace "Yearmove" has a number the Result field reads "#ERROR", so both when the condition is met and when it is not. I have tried populating the "YEAR" field with both text (e.g. "2014") and non-text (e.g. 2014) but get the same result. All data is numeric. 
Here is what a section of the results look like:

```
SCHOOL  Year    BldgNo  Yearmove    Result
254     2014     254                   0
256     2014     256                   0
260     2014     260                   0
261     2014     261                   0
262     2014     202                   0
301     2014     301                   0
307     2014     307     2019        #ERROR
313     2014     313     2019        #ERROR
314     2014     314                   0
321     2014     321                   0
322     2014     322                   0
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data (full row with result of expression) and data types on all columns involved, please?

Comment: What's the best way to paste table data?

Comment: Close. You can edit your question and use some of the formatting tools to make it look a little more readable. I'd do it but it looks like you have 5 columns and 44 pieces of data and I'm not sure where the line breaks are. Plus no `#ERROR` values?

Comment: Added result data to original post

Comment: Are you sure all your data are numeric? What are the datatypes in the table from which you are selecting these data? If I change either of the datatypes of `z.Year` or `ProgMoveBuild.yearmove` to text I get this error. I.e. they they are different this error will happen. If they are the same (text or number) the error does not happen.

Comment: Brad you had it right, it was a type mismatch, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query throws an error, *"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"*:

```sql
SELECT IIf('2014'=2014, 1, 0)
```

So I suspect your *Year* and *yearmove* fields are different datatypes: one is numeric; and the other is text.

Find out what datatypes you're dealing with ...

```sql
SELECT
    z.Year,
    TypeName(z.Year) AS TypeOfYear,
    ProgMoveBuild.yearmove,
    TypeName(ProgMoveBuild.yearmove) AS TypeOfyearmove
FROM [whatever you have now as your data source(s)]
```

If changing the datatype of one of those fields not practical, you can cast a field's values to another type for the `IIf` condition in your query.  `CStr()` will cast a numeric value to a string.  And `Val()` will cast a string value to a number.  However, either of those functions will complain when you give them Nulls.  So you can use `Nz()` to substitute something else for Null before you feed the value to `CStr()` or `Val()`.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was a type mismatch I think it's resolved.